# Prove if $\vec{w} \perp \vec{u}, \vec{v}$ then $\vec{w} \perp (r\vec{u}+s\vec{v})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Exercise 1.2.44 (*Fraleigh - Linear Algebra*):

For vectors $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$, and $\vec{w}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and for scalars $r$ and $s$, prove that, if $\vec{w}$ is perpendicular to both $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$, then $\vec{w}$ is perpendicular to $r\vec{u}+s\vec{v}$.

I have started with the geometric solution. It is this:

[image: Geometric solution]

My next step is to prove it analytically; but first, I need to know if this geometric solutions is correct.

Comment: Yes. Your geometric intuition is correct.

Comment: Hint: $\vec w \cdot \vec u = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Your geometric intuition is correct. Now, for the analytic proof: Let $\vec{u}$, $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{w}$ be in $\mathbf{R}^n$ such that $\vec{w}$ is perpendicular to $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$. This means that the dot product between each vector is naught, i.e. $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u}=0$ and $\vec{w}\cdot\vec{v}=0$. Now let's compute $\vec{w}\cdot(r\vec{u}+s\vec{v})$, we have: $$\begin{align}
\vec{w}\cdot(r\vec{u}+s\vec{v}) 
&= 
\vec{w}\cdot r\vec{u}+\vec{w}\cdot s\vec{v}\\
&=
r(\vec{w}\cdot\vec{u})+s(\vec{w}\cdot\vec{v})\\
&=
r\cdot0+s\cdot0\\
&=0\tag*{$\square$}
\end{align}$$